What can I do about the crumbling edge of this concrete driveway?
Two problems at the end of our driveway:

driveway was poured about 2 years ago (before we bought) directly over a massive tree root with seemingly no preparation. Bits of concrete are predictably cracking and breaking off, with more cracks visible. This is difficult to drive over due to reduced traction and unevenness.
the slope onto the city asphalt is pretty steep and scrapes the bottom of the car at most angles.

Context - live in DC, mostly warm but it does freeze
Anything we can do to address either or both of these? We tried buying a rubber ramp but it was too tall and didn’t help the root problem at all. We’re open to short term fixes that just bandaid the problem as well as real solutions. Would prefer not to get rid of the root because it will kill the tree. Thank you!

One tree root might not kill/hurt the tree.  You want an tree expert to help/advise.  Most trees have many roots.

A pic or 2 would help. I have seen a big 5 inch root cut out to properly lay pavers. I bet that the tree would die...I lost that bet.

Pictures would help a lot. Please [edit] to add some.  It would be unusual for one root to kill the tree if cut/removed, just as it would be unusual for one branch to kill the tree if broken, cut, or removed. A typical rule of thumb is that most trees will manage if you remove less than 1/3 the growth in a given year and let them recover from that before cutting any more.

I think it is the treatment of the cut root after, that is more important.  Cutting with a saw and just leaving it, might kill the the tree from disease/rot, if not treated.

Is there supposed to be a photo?
